# Execute Code in Parallel in PHP to minimize execution time

Tags: php, curl, parallel-processing, pthreads, execution-time

**Initial Condition**: I have code written in php file. initially i was executing code, it was taking 30 seconds to execute. In this file the code was called 5 times.

**What will happen next**:Let if i need to execute this code 50 times then it will take 300 seconds in one execution in browser.next for 500 times 3000 secs. So it is serial execution of code.

**What I Need**: i need to execute this code in parallel. like several instance. So i would like to minimize the execution time so user has not wait for such long time.

**What I Did**: i used PHP CURL to execute this code parallel. I called this file several times to minimize the execution time.

So **I want to know** that is this method is correct. How much CURL i can execute and how much resources it require. It need a better method that how could i execute this code in parallel with tutorial.

any help will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest option without changing your code (too much), though, would be to call PHP through the command line and not CURL. This cuts the overhead of APACHE (both in memory and speed), networking etc. Plus Curl is not a portable option as some servers can't see themselves (in network terms).

```
$process1 = popen('php myfile.php [parameters]');
$process2 = popen('php myfile.php [parameters]');

// get response from children : you can loop until all completed
$response1 = stream_get_contents($process1);
$response2 = stream_get_contents($process2);
```

You'll need to remove any reference to apache added variables in $_SERVER, and replace $_GET with argv/argc references. Both otherwise it should just work.

But the best solution will probably be pThreads (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php) that allow you to do what you want. Will require some editing of code (and installing, possibly) but does what you're asking.

Comment: hi
popen ask for 2 parameter. second parameter for mode. so which mode i need to use? another if myfile.php in above directory. as well its not working. How to check popen is working or not?

Comment: I was only giving pointers: the manual has the details http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php  You'll need to add in the missing bits such as fread() and fclose(). Note that there are other ways of calling processes (e.g. proc_open) as well.

Answer (score 0):

php curl is low enough overhead to not have to worry about it.  If you can make loopback calls to a server farm through a load balancer, that's a good use case for curl.  I've also used `pcntl_fork()` for same-host parallelism, but it's harder to set up.  I've written classes built on both; see my php lib at https://github.com/andrasq/quicklib for ideas (or just borrow code, it's open source)

Comment: But how can i use pcntl_fork() here. I dont have any idea. pls explain with respect this example. i need to send 1000 mail in one minute from different sender mail ids and to different receivers. means function or code get each time different sender mail id and receiver id form another function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Gearman. Documentation :
http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php

Comment: But how can i use gearman here. I dont have any idea. pls explain with respect this example. i need to send 1000 mail in one minute from different sender mail ids and to different receivers.

means function or code get each time different sender mail id and receiver id form another function.